# Delay Page reload after form submit to Salesforce

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, delay

I'm working on a small feedback tab on my website to submit information to Salesforce and it's submitting correctly but I need a delay before the page reloads so the user can read the "thank you" message.

Here's a sample of what's going on: http://jsfiddle.net/RNg28/

Note: It works perfectly fine despite the {"error": "Please use POST request"} message.
If anyone can give ideas on how to use ajax for this, that would be awesome as well!

Thanks!
Mike

Comment: No comprendo. The feedback message is submitted via AJAX so why refresh the page? Surely you can allow the user to stay where he is then navigate away if he chooses by normal means (eg. navbar). The only additional code you need is an `error` handler (similar to the `success` handler) to display an error message but not to destroy the form nor to hide the feedback pop-out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reload a webpage using JavaScript just use `window.location.reload()`.
You will want to add that after your tab slides in [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/RNg28/1/)